# How to check if message-key is empty?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have the following in my .jsp file:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
...
<fmt:message key="mykey.${country}" />
```

For some countries this key exists and the message is shown as expected, for others it does not exist. If it does not exist I get the following output:

```
???mykey.DE???
```

which I don't want. I would expect to have no output if the key does not exist.

`mykey.${country}` resolves to either

- mykey.DE
- mykey.SE
- mykey.US
- mykey.GB
- ...

I don't know which one it will be but I need to check if it exists as a variable.

**Is there a way to check this or to hide the unwanted output?**

---

What I tried so far:

I tried to surround it with

```
<c:if test="$(not empty mykey.${country})">
  <fmt:message key="mykey.${country}" />
</c:if>
```

but it doesn't work: the message is never displayed, even if the key exists.

I also tried to put it into a local variable first:

```
<c:set var="localVar" value="mykey.${country}" />
<c:out value="${localVar}" /> <!-- this prints 'mykey.DE' correctly -->
<c:if test="!empty ${localVar}">
    <div style="padding-top:10px;">
    <fmt:message key="mykey.${country}" />
    </div>
</c:if>
```

But the check does not work as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
<c:set var="localvar"><fmt:message key="mykey.${country}" /></c:set>

<c:if test="${!fn:startsWith(localvar,'???')}">
   ${localvar}
</c:if>
```

Not exactly pretty, though. Another option might be to write a custom message tag:

```
<%@ tag body-content="empty" %>
<%@ attribute name="key" required="true" %>
<%@ attribute name="defaultvalue" required="true"  %>

<%@ taglib prefix="c"   uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"      %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"       %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<c:set var="msg"><fmt:message key="${key}" /></c:set>

<c:choose>

    <c:when test="${!fn:startsWith(msg,'???')}">
        ${msg}
    </c:when>    

    <c:otherwise>
        ${defaultvalue}
    </c:otherwise>

</c:choose>
```

And then use as follows:

```
<my:message key="mykey.${country}" defaultvalue=""/>
```

Comment: Wow. Pardon me for not searching SO first for an existing answer, but isn't that what the OP is supposed to do? As a bonus I'll put my custom tag here. It's a fairly common approach I thought. I hate to admit that I even use the `my` prefix on the taglib...

Answer (score 1):

Is this  `mykey.${country}` is this correct format? Either make it below format or get the value out to a local var first.

```
<c:if test="$(not empty mykey.country)">
  <fmt:message key="mykey.country" />
```

### Some tips

if yourParam exists/ is not null:

```
<c:if test="${param.yourParam != null}"></c:if>
```

if yourParam does not exist/ is null

```
<c:if test="${param.yourParam == null}"></c:if>
```

if yourParam is not empty (not empty string and not null)

```
<c:if test="${!empty param.yourParam}"></c:if>
```

if yourParam is empty (empty string or null)

```
<c:if test="${empty param.yourParam}"></c:if>
```

Comment: If I put it in a local variable like `<c:set var="localVar" value="mykey.${country}" />`. Then I would'nt need to check if localVar is empty (I know it is not) - i would need to check the variable which name is saved to localVar, I guess something like `<c:if test="${${localVar} != null}">`. ? The problem is that I build a string which will be the variable's name I want to check.

Comment: This answer is wrong. OP doesn't want to check if a key is empty. OP wants to check if the value associated with the key is empty.